# Jquery: Submit form with confimation and then post request with callback

Tags: onclick, repeat

Its hard to say shortly.. but i'll try...
I have a form, that generated with jquery. In this form dynamicaly filled fields, what I need to send to PHP:

```
    function openCropSettings (id) {
        target = '<img src="'+'uploads/'+getCookie("fo_randomPath")+'/'+$("li[data-jfiler-index="+id+"]").find(".fo_item-name").text()+"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime()+'" id="target" />';
        settings_template = 
        '<div class="fo_target-container">'
            +target+
            '<form class="fo_submit_crop" id="fo_crop-form" onsubmit="return checkCoords();" action="#" >\
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />\
                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />\
                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />\
                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />\
                <input type="hidden" id="image_id" name="image_id" value="'+id+'"/>\
                <input type="hidden" id="image_name" name="image_name" value="'+image_name+'"/>\
                <input type="hidden" id="path" name="path" value="'+path+'"/>\
                <textarea id="fo_add-crop-comment" name="textarea" placeholder="Can leave a comment here..."></textarea>\
                <input type="submit" id="submitCrop" value="" />\
                <input class="button_cancel" type="button" />\
                <input class="button_rotate" type="button" value="" />\
            </form>\
        </div>';
        $(".fo_crop-settings").html(settings_template);
        $(".fo_crop-settings").css('margin-top', '0px');
        $(target).on('load', function(){
            $('#target').Jcrop({
                boxWidth: limitsW,
                boxHeight: limitsH, 
                allowSelect: false,
                bgOpacity: 0.3,
                onSelect: updateCoords
            }, function(){
                $("#submitCrop").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(".fo_confirm").css('margin-top', '0');
                });

                $("#confirm_abort").click(function() {
                    $(".fo_confirm").css('margin-top', '-120px');           
                });

                $("#confirm_confirmation").click(function() {
                    form_data = $(".fo_submit_crop").serialize();
                    $.post('uploader/ajax_upload_file.php', form_data, function(data){
/*
Here I collect PHP respons, that give me a data with new(croped) image properies. And after this, generate new thumb on page with custom function:*/
                        createMask($(thumbMaskPlace), orientations, formatRatio, widthless, data[1], data[2], dontCrop, border);
                        $(target).html(thumbImage);             
                        console.log(data);
                    });             
                });

                $(".button_cancel").click(function() {
                    $(".fo_crop-settings").html('');
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

This form can be created several time at single session(may be a lot times). The problem appear then I use it second, third and all next times. Each time, response from PHP increase at 1. So.. second send of form data, take two responses. Third three responses.. Response contains corresponding reiteration of current sended data and look like this(This is console.log(data) at end of function):

```
controller.js:572 ["0", "700", "469", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["0", "700", "469", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["1", "256", "172", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["1", "256", "172", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["1", "256", "172", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["2", "232", "155", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["2", "231", "155", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["2", "231", "155", "hor", "0.67"]

controller.js:572 ["2", "231", "155", "hor", "0.67"]
```

And PHP work on it every single iterate... (((
If I use it like this:

```
$("#submitCrop").click(function() {
e.preventDefault();
                        form_data = $(".fo_submit_crop").serialize();
                        $.post('uploader/ajax_upload_file.php', form_data, function(data)
```

everything work fine... but now I have skiped confirmation from user process.

**Please note that I have intentionally removed some lines of code in which a calculated variables used further in form and in code**

So... what can I do, to have confirmation and correct response process?

Sorry if all this look not so good.... I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with: **unbind()**

```
$("#confirm_confirmation").unbind() //<===here the problem is solved!
$("#confirm_confirmation").click(function() {
form_data = $(".fo_submit_crop").serialize();
$.post('uploader/ajax_upload_file.php', form_data, function(data)......
```